# Функция onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  function chg(id){
    if (document.getElementById(id).src.indexOf("images/banner3.jpg")>0){
      document.getElementById(id).src="images/big-logo.png"
    }else{
      document.getElementById(id).src="images/banner3.jpg"
    }
  }
</script>
<img src="images/banner3.jpg" id="img_1" onClick="chg(this.id)">
```

Добрый день, с помощью данного когда при нажатии на картинку она меняется на 2 и при втором нажатии обратно. Мне же нужно чтобы после перового нажатия, через n времени картинка снова поменялась на первую.

Comment: и что у вас не получается ? опять "сами мы в javacript 0 помогите пожалуйста!" ?

Comment: Да действительно в  javacript 0, потому что сейчас плотно изучаю и делаю проект на html + css, однако для полной реализации мне нужна такая функция.

Comment: и что вы предлагаете ? написать за вас эту функцию ? 30$/hr

Comment: Я не прошу писать за меня данную функцию, я прошу помочь или хотя бы дать пару советов. Не зря же я написал это в "вопросах".

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

```
function func() {
    $("#img_1").attr('src', 'img.png');
}

setTimeout(func, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов решения - setTimeout. Выполняет код(или функцию), указанный в первом аргументе, асинхронно, с задержкой в миллисекундах..

Пример ТОЛЬКО для понимания, НЕ использовать код в реальном проекте! (учесть все рекомендации использования метода и т.д.)

```
<script>
function chg(id){
    document.getElementById(id).src = 'images/big-logo.png';
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('"+id+"').src = 'images/banner3.jpg'", 3000);
}
</script>
<img src="images/banner3.jpg" id="img_1" onClick="chg(this.id)">
```

---

долго печатал :)

Comment: Благодарствую обоим, метод работает.